# Open iOS Developer Menu programmatically / command

Tags: ios, react-native

This isn't exactly a critical bug, but I always feel weird shaking phones at my desk at work, even more so when it doesn't work first time. If we start talking about shaking iPad Pros, it just feels wrong.

On Android, I can run the following command: `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU`

Is there an iOS equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10191

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly no.

You can vote for it on [Canny here](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/shake-gesture-should-not-be-only-way-to-reach-dev-menu-on-physical-device). Until then, your best bet for iOS is to use a workaround such as one of the ones suggested from the original [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10191). For example, creating your own multi-touch shortcut for opening the dev menu as seen [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10191#issuecomment-277208461). It's not ideal but it should work. (code copy pasted below)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  PanResponder,
  NativeModules,
}            from 'react-native';


const DevMenuTrigger = ({children}) => {
  const {DevMenu} = NativeModules;
  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
      if (gestureState.numberActiveTouches === 3) {
        DevMenu.show();
      }
    },
  });
  return <View style={{flex: 1}} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>{children}</View>;
};


...

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', (): any => <DevMenuTrigger><MyApp></DevMenuTrigger>
```